# How to add a row in a tabular but no vertical lines

Tags: tables

I'd like to know how to add a row (in this case the last one) without adding further vertical lines from the {|c|c...} of the tabular so that the lines dont go over my bottomrule like in this example.

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within \linewidth horizontally
    \begin{tabular}{|c|ccccccccccccc|}
        \toprule
        Feature & $G_1$ & $G_2$ & $G_3$ & ... & $G_{c-1}$ & $G_c$ & & $G_1^M$ & $G_2^M$ & $G_3^M$ & ... & $G_{c-1}^M$ & $G_c^M$\\
        \midrule
        $\varphi_1$ & .4 & .3 & .61 & ...& $\infty$ & .1 & & $\infty$ & .12 & NaN & ... & .83 & NaN\\ [-1.5ex]
        \specialrule{1.8pt}{1pt}{1pt} \\ [-1.5ex]
        $\varphi_2$  & 1 & 9.5 & 49 & ... & 6.5 & 21 & & 16 & 34.5 & 44 & ... & 210 & 32\\
        $\varphi_3$ & 10 & 10.01 & 10 & ... & 10 & 9.99 & & 10.01 & 9.98 & 10 & ... & 10.1 & 10.04\\ [-1.5ex]
        \specialrule{1.8pt}{1pt}{1pt} \\ [-1.5ex]
        $\varphi_4$ & 2 & 19 & 98 & ... & 13 & 42 & & 32 & 69 & 88 & ... & 420 & 64\\ [-1.5ex]
        \specialrule{1.8pt}{1pt}{1pt} \\ [-1.5ex]
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
```

[image: interpreted latex code]

Without the last \specialrule it works just fine

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|ccccccccccccc|}
        \toprule
        Feature & $G_1$ & $G_2$ & $G_3$ & ... & $G_{c-1}$ & $G_c$ & & $G_1^M$ & $G_2^M$ & $G_3^M$ & ... & $G_{c-1}^M$ & $G_c^M$\\
        \midrule
        $\varphi_1$ & .4 & .3 & .61 & ...& $\infty$ & .1 & & $\infty$ & .12 & NaN & ... & .83 & NaN\\ [-1.5ex]
        \specialrule{1.8pt}{1pt}{1pt} \\ [-1.5ex]
        $\varphi_2$  & 1 & 9.5 & 49 & ... & 6.5 & 21 & & 16 & 34.5 & 44 & ... & 210 & 32\\
        $\varphi_3$ & 10 & 10.01 & 10 & ... & 10 & 9.99 & & 10.01 & 9.98 & 10 & ... & 10.1 & 10.04\\ [-1.5ex]
        \specialrule{1.8pt}{1pt}{1pt} \\ [-1.5ex]
        $\varphi_4$ & 2 & 19 & 98 & ... & 13 & 42 & & 32 & 69 & 88 & ... & 420 & 64\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
```

[image]

I hope you can help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your preamble to make everything as a minimum working example?

Comment: To quote from the [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual: "Never, ever use vertical rules." (One should adhere to this at least when using `booktabs`, I think.)

Comment: also avoid scaling tables `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within \linewidth horizontally`  just makes inconsistent font sizes and rule widths, not scaling is almost always a better option.

Comment: I followed the tip by @schtandard and just left them out.
Dont think it necessarily looks better but it doesnt look worse so it's a win.

Comment: What's the point of your `\specialrule`s? Are they meant to be a strikethrough?

Comment: Yes they are meant to be strikethroughs. Since normal hline were too thin for the way I want to use them (stylistic device) the ```\specialrule``` was the most fitting thing I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's try to improve this table.
First of all, to quote the [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual

> 1. Never, ever use vertical rules.
> 2. Never use double rules.

(only the first rule applies to your case). Just getting rid of the vertical rules improves your table and make subsequent steps easier.

---

Next, the `\resizebox`: It's generally a bad idea to resize a block of text (like a table) like this. It leads to all kinds of inconsistencies. If your table doesn't fit, you need to change your table, not just scale it. If your table is very large, maybe it is best to put it on a page on its own in landscape. If it is only very wide, maybe splitting it up in two could be reasonable (this depends on the content).  If the width of the rows is determined by one very large cell, maybe you could change just that cell (e.g. abbreviate "Feature" in your table).

As a last resort, it is usually okay to have the text in your table be `\small` (but not any smaller than that!) or slightly reduce the value of `\tabcolsep` to a smaller value (the default is `12pt`).

---

Whenever you typeset numbers (not only in tables), I would recommend using the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package. The most prominent feature in your table is that all the decimal points will be aligned. I recommend having a look at the manual to get an overview of its features.

---

It is better to use the `@` specifier in the `tabular` column setup to add extra space or symbols between columns than to explicitly type an extra column in every row. This also gives you more control over the actual dimension of the added space.

---

Finally, you should never type `...` in LaTeX, that's what `\dots` is for. Since the spacing of `\dots` is a bit wide by default, you will probably want to load the [`ellipsis`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ellipsis) package to adjust it.

---

Okay, after adjusting your table accoring to all this, it is  still 70 pt too wide, even using `\small` (that is using just `\documentclass{article}`, it may be different depending on your page size and margins). We can make it fit by setting `\tabcolsep=3.5pt`. Just looking at this isolated table, I would say that's okay. You should however consider if that's not the case in the context of your entire document.

I replaced your `NaN` with a macro `\nan`. This makes it easier to change the symbol you are using to represent this. Usually, I would prefer `--` or a different symbol to othe rather clumsy `NaN`, but that may just be personal taste. (Also, it doesn't really work with strikethrough rows.)

Lastly, I replaced your rather hacky method for striking table rows with a TikZ based solution. This should prove rather more flexible and not interfere with the row spacing in any way. Personally, I don't see why you want to strike the rows at all (I think just mentioning in the table caption / the document text that all values except `\varphi_2` were discarded would be better in all cases I can think of), but there you go. If you really want the line to be thick you can uncomment the relevant line, but I would deem it undesirable to have the strikethrough line be thicker than the `\midrule` as well as find it unnecessarily difficult to read the text behind the thick line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\def\ellipsisgap{.1ex}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
    \tikzset{
        strike through node/.style={
            shape=rectangle,
            inner sep=0pt,
            outer sep=0pt,
        },
        strike through line/.style={
%           thick,
        }
    }
    \def\switch@current@strikethroughpoint@toA{%
        \gdef\current@strikethroughpoint{strike through point A}%
        \global\let\switch@current@strikethroughpoint\switch@current@strikethroughpoint@toB
    }
    \def\switch@current@strikethroughpoint@toB{%
        \gdef\current@strikethroughpoint{strike through point B}%
        \global\let\switch@current@strikethroughpoint\switch@current@strikethroughpoint@toA
    }
    \switch@current@strikethroughpoint@toB
    \newif\ifexecute@strikethrough
    \def\strikethroughpoint{%
        \switch@current@strikethroughpoint
        \tikz [remember picture, baseline=(\current@strikethroughpoint.base)] \node [strike through node] (\current@strikethroughpoint) {\vphantom{0}};%
        \ifexecute@strikethrough
            \tikz [remember picture, overlay] \draw [strike through line] (strike through point A.west) -- (strike through point B.east);
            \global\execute@strikethroughfalse
        \fi
    }
    \def\strikethisrow{\global\execute@strikethroughtrue}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\nan{{NaN}}
%\newcommand*\nan{{--}}

\begin{document}\makeatletter

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \small
    \tabcolsep=3.5pt
    \begin{tabular}{>{\strikethroughpoint}c S[table-format=2.1] *{2}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}\dots\hspace{2\tabcolsep}} S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=2.2] @{\hspace{4\tabcolsep}} *{2}{S[table-format=2.2]} S[table-format=2.0] @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}\dots\hspace{2\tabcolsep}} S[table-format=3.2] S[table-format=2.2]<{\strikethroughpoint}}\toprule
        feat.   &   {$G_1$} &   {$G_2$} &   {$G_3$} &   {$G_{c-1}$} &   {$G_c$} &   {$G_1^M$}   &   {$G_2^M$}   &   {$G_3^M$}   &   {$G_{c-1}^M$}   &   {$G_c^M$}   \\\midrule
        \strikethisrow
        $\varphi_1$ &   .4  &   .3  &   .61 &   $\infty$    &   .1  &   $\infty$    &   .12 &   \nan    &   .83 &   \nan    \\
        $\varphi_2$ &   1   &   9.5 &   49  &   6.5 &   21  &   16  &   34.5    &   44  &   210 &   32  \\
        \strikethisrow
        $\varphi_3$ &   10  &   10.01   &   10  &   10  &   9.99    &   10.01   &   9.98    &   10  &   10.1    &   10.04   \\
        \strikethisrow
        $\varphi_4$ &   2   &   19  &   98  &   13  &   42  &   32  &   69  &   88  &   420 &   64  \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]